# Install valgrind for android, C compiler doesn't work

Tags: android, windows, cygwin, valgrind

I'm trying to configure valgrind for android on Windows 7. I'm using guide from [this site](http://www.programering.com/a/MjM3UzMwATE.html), but there is a problem with C compiler while configure. I'm using cygwin.

Error:

`configure:3531: error: in /cygdrive/c/Tools/valgrind-3.9.0':
configure:3533: error: C compiler cannot create executables`

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export NDKROOT=C:/Tools/AndroidNDK-r6
export HWKIND=generic         # A generic Android device. eg, Pandaboard
export AR=$NDKROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar.exe
export LD=$NDKROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe
export CC=$NDKROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe
CPPFLAGS="--sysroot=$NDKROOT/platforms/android-3/arch-arm -DANDROID_HARDWARE_$HWKIND" \
CFLAGS="--sysroot=$NDKROOT/platforms/android-3/arch-arm" \
./configure --prefix=/data/local/Inst \
--host=armv7-unknown-linux --target=armv7-unknown-linux \
--with-tmpdir=/sdcard
make
make install
```

and [config.log file](http://pastebin.com/yrtEiK2Q)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, there's a kind of a problem executing the compiler from within the NDK folder. The log file states:

```
configure:3422: checking for C compiler version
configure:3431: C:/Tools/AndroidNDK-r6
/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe
 --version >&5
./configure: line 3433: C:/Tools/AndroidNDK-r6
/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe
: No such file or directory
```

So next you want to make sure that the path actually exists and the compiler executable is executable indeed. You can try yourself to type directly in cygwin shell:

```
C:/Tools/AndroidNDK-r6/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe -v
```

...and see what happens.